# All libraries must have the exact version

Tags: java, android, gradle, sdk

I dont quite understand [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8Cij.png) my sdk version is the same as my 'appcompat' and 'recyclerview' but it still has an error to it,I have tried rebuild and clean the project but still geting the same result, I have the same project to this one but it doesn't have an error like this one, any idea whats going on here?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.parasitologymemorization.parasitologymemorization"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '**/*.so'])
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.satyan:sugar:1.5'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.beardedhen:androidbootstrap:2.3.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.wonderkiln:camerakit:0.12.0'
    compile(name: 'tensorflow', ext: 'aar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the `com.android.support:animated vector drawable:27.0.0`" in the `build.gradle` file and then change 27.0.0 to 26.0.1 and that sync the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

`Android Studio` makes a lot of files as caches and does not delete them. This can cause trouble when there is a need to make new files, so clearing 'cacheswill clear the oldcache` and make Android Studio faster.

So you need to  Invalidate Caches/Restart in Android Studio.

Comment: delete idea gradle build folders

Answer (score 0):

Whichever versions it says are wrong in the error message, compile the newest version in your gradle file, even if you don't think you're using them.  I've run into this multiple times and that always fixes it.

For example, you should manually compile the recyclerview dependency with version 27.0.0

Comment: but that would give me an error because im only using sdk 26

Comment: So then knock the ones that it says are 27.0.0 down to 26.x.x

Comment: In your error message it says something about vector drawable version 27.0.0, you should manually compile that as version 26.0.1